# Copy WAV file to clipboard

Tags: java, javascript, python, cmd, clipboard

I would like to copy a local WAV file to my clipboard using Java, Javascript, Python, or using the Windows command line.

Basically I am open to ANY way to copy a WAV file to my clipboard, but those are my preferred languages for doing it.  Most preferably Javascript.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to copy the contents of the Wave file (the binary data) or the reference to the File itself...?

Comment: I believe I want the reference to the file.  Basically I want to copy a file to my clipboard, then emulate a "Ctrl+V" keystroke in Ableton Live, and have it actually paste a WAV file into Live.  I'm not sure but I think at one point I tried to copy the raw WAV data and it didn't work

Comment: @blisstdev: Have you tried to do as I suggested? What does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You could using [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library for Python on Windows.Here is some code that copies a file to the clipboard, and reading it from the clipboard:

```
import win32clipboard

with open('input.wav','rb') as input:
    wav = input.read()

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_WAVE, wav)

file_from_clipboard = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_WAVE)

with open('output.wav','wb') as output:
    output.write( file_from_clipboard )
```

If you want to insert into the clipboard only the path, you can do so:

```
path = 'Path to wav file'
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText( path, win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)

#Get text from clipboard
path_from_clip = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)

print path_from_clip
```

Or, even more simply, you can use [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/1.3). Pyperclip is cross-platform module for accessing the clipboard in Python:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('Path to wav file')

#Get text from clipboard
print pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Neither the pyperclip nor the CF_TEXT methods which just copy the text of the file path to the clipboard work in the way that I want, though may be useful at some point.

The CF_WAVE method has yet to work for me, but I'm still trying to play around with it when I have time...

Comment: Hey, so I finally had a chance to play around with this a bunch, and I still can't get it to work.  Basically I'm checking what's getting copied to the clipboard in a Clipboard Viewer and when I do it natively (i.e. Ctrl+C), I get something like "E:\DOCUME~1\PROGRA~1\Python\PARTIALWAVEFILENAME~1.WAV", whereas when I do it with the string file buffer (wav.open('path').read()) or with a bytearray (bytearray(wav.open('path').read()), I get "The information is in binary format.  Clipbook Viewer cannot display this format," and I can't paste it anywhere.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I want to paste this file into a different application, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with clipboard ownership?  Or something to do with a "handle" to the buffer object.
http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32clipboard__SetClipboardData_meth.html